# Shuffle some results in mysql dataset

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has a column names `order` and I want to sort results in ascending order of `order`. Easy enough.

However, `order` can also have a value of zero which in my case is special because zeroes mean that these items get pushed to the back of the set in random order (in cases there are multiple zero value rows).

That is to say: `5 6 3 0 0 2 4 1 0 -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0`

Where the last 3 rows are shuffled every time I make the query. I'm currently solving this via PHP but I was wondering if some of the SQL pros around here could give me pointers for a MySQL solution?

Comment: So you already figured out how to put the zeros at the end, and just want their order to be constant from query to query?

Comment: I used PHP to solve this. ie. taking the results and slicing the array to grab all the zero fields, shuffle them and attach them to the end of the array. What I'm looking for now is a MySQL solution because doing this on PHP feels slow.

Comment: I don't have the chance to test it on my local machine, but you should try the following: `SELECT [...] ORDER BY IF(order > 0; 0; 1) ASC, order ASC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2852/10):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY
  (CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN 999999999 ELSE id END) ASC,
  (SELECT RAND()) ASC
```

The `SELECT` in the `ORDER BY` is important. Without it the `RAND()` function would only be called once and it wouldn't shuffle.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. That's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you

```
SELECT `order`
FROM table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `order` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, `order`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT      order,
            CASE
                WHEN order=0 THEN 9999999
                ELSE order
                END AS ordermeby
FROM        table
ORDER BY    ordermeby;
```